# How to parse request.body into json in django

Tags: json, django, post, request

When I use Postman to send a post request to my django server, I receive request.body like user=abc&pwd=123, not like a json
And when I use my android app to send a post request to my django server, I also receive the request.body like user=abc&pwd=123
How can I parse this kind of format like user=abc&pwd=123 into json in python?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, so please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other effort you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 'user=abc&pwd=123&test_empty='
c = [(o.split('=')) for o in a.split('&') if '=' in o]
print c
```